# Converting IMDB and Wikipedia bookmarks into a list that includes the movie summary?

Tags: bookmark

I have hundreds of saved movie bookmarks on IMDB and Wikipedia. I would like to know if there is a way to export them all in a txt or doc or pdf file (or other searchable format) ordered by year of release (or if that's impossible, genre or alphabetical order or some other classification) with the movie summary (on Wiki, the intro paragraph) under each item. Cheers.

Comment: What web browser are your bookmarks stored on?

Comment: Can you code? Do you want to learn? That is almost certainly the only way to get this done (but it won't be terribly difficult and could be a fun learning project :-)

Comment: Hello and thanks for the replies. I'm on Firefox. I don't mind learning some programming (I'm assuming it's going to be Python or something similar?) :))